# How can I integrate the Spotify Webplayer SDK in React Native and stream music from Spotify within my application?

Tags: react-native, expo, spotify

I want to stream music from Spotify in my React Native application created with Expo. This can be done in a browser with the [Spotify Webplayer SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/), and I would like to use it in my application as well if that is possible.

I've tried to inject the script provided in the link above into my react native application with [React Native Webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) and initializing the playback device like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
            ...
        })
    }
})
```

But this does not seem to work.

There are libraries for controlling an **existing playback device** like [Spotify Web API Node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node). Which means, that if I were to create a playback device in my application, I would then be able to control it.

It it possible to use the SDK to initialize a valid playback device in my react native application so that I can stream music to it?